# InterBase  database file appears corrupt () 

Tags: .net, interbase

I am getting this error when I try to delete some rows in InterBase database,

but for those ROWS I can fire SQL queries for SELECT and also UPDATE ... but not delete.

What went wrong , what is the possible solution.

Comment: Any triggers or Foreign keys?

Comment: Sorry , for late response 
yes target table have both Triggers and Foreign Keys

Comment: @van, its Borland InterBase V 1.1.0.23

Answer (score 0):

You could try backing up the database then doing a restore.  We have found this deals with most Interbase DB corruption problems.

Sometimes though, you can't backup the DB in the first place because of the corruption.  In this case we generally create an empty copy of the DB which only has the tables defined (without any foreign keys) and then pump the data across from the corrupt DB to the empty one.  We then add the rest of the foreign keys, stored proc's etc...  Very long winded, but as a last ditch effort it has never failed us (yet).